# MySQL error code 1292

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1292

When running the query below I keep getting a warning:

> Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Resolved Date'.

I'm trying to extract only strings that are dates from `str_customvalue`. That is why I did a `DATE(DATE(str_customvalue)) is not null`.

```
    Select
    case str_category
        when
            ('Resolved Date'
                and (status = 'Closed')
                and (DATE(str_customvalue) is not null)
            )
        then
            cast(str_customvalue as datetime)
        else cast(str_diff_date` as datetime)
    end AS last_diff_date

    From table
```

Is there any way to remove this warning? The query works fine, but in order for my script to pass QA I need to remove this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using IF() statement as such:

```
Select
IF ( str_category = 'Resolved Date' and
   and (status = 'Closed')
   and (DATE(str_customvalue) is not null, 
   cast(str_customvalue as datetime),
   cast(str_diff_date` as datetime))
   AS last_diff_date

From table
```